# CGridView for custom CActiveDataProvider select

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, cactivedataprovider

So the problem is, that I have a view that will render a CGridView containing a count value. I had to make a custom CDbCriteria so that I could select the right infos. Now I can't display it in a CGridView.

Here is my controller action that builds the CActiveDataProvider:

```
public function actionListProducts(){
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'rp_product as product, count(rp_id) as cnt';
    $criteria->group = 'product';

    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('report', array( 'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));

    $this->render('listProducts',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

I am trying to display it in this CGridView:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'reports-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'columns'=>array(
        'product',
        'cnt'
    ),
));
```

I know the data is fetched properly because my CGridView has the right number of rows... What am I suppose to write in the 'columns' description?

Thank you

Comment: I can't see any sensible data in there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the aliases `product` and `cnt` (var AS alias), you have to make a public property of it in the model Report.

Example:

```
Model extends CActiveRecord {
....
public $product;
public $cnt;
...
}
```

Comment: Ok, i think i misunderstand your question. Do you get any output or not? Do you have a method getReport() in Report?

Comment: I have no output. There is the right number of rows but they are empty. What would getReport() do?

Comment: @veelen. You are correct. We have to declare the variables which are all alias we used in our query. +1 for that.

Comment: I added them in my model, still nothing displays. Do I have to make some other functions?

Comment: @Bismuth If you don't use a public property (what i think you should do),  you can use it to return a value

Comment: @Bismuth You dont need to use getReport, you need to make a public property report.

Comment: @Veelen I was putting it private! Ok now everything works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Bismuth It can also be done with a private property, but then you dó need `getReport()`, and make it return `$this->_report`.